# Подключить ф-цию из другого файла по событию click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой инпут

```
<input type="text" class="correctMoney">
```

Есть функция ну например

```
 function correctMoney (e){
     alert($(e.currentTarget))
}
```

как мне прописать событие например вот так

```
$('.correctMoney').on('click', correctmoney(event, {forDisplay: true, classOfDomElement: 'resOne,resTwo', showPoint: false}));
```

просто если я прописываю так то у меня вываливается ошибка при загрузке страницы

```
Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined
```

ЗЫ пытаюсь модифицировать тут [github](https://github.com/gogas/correctMoney) index.html с

```
<input type="text" class="correctMoney" onkeyup="correctmoney(event, {forDisplay: true, classOfDomElement: 'resOne,resTwo', showPoint: false})">
```

на

```
    <input type="text" class="correctMoney">
<script>
        $('.correctMoney').on('click', correctmoney(event, {forDisplay: true, classOfDomElement: 'resOne,resTwo', showPoint: false}));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код в атрибутах оборачивается в анонимную функцию.
Так что Вам тоже это нужно сделать, только явно:

```js
function correctMoney(e){
  alert($(e.currentTarget));
}

$('.correctMoney').on('click', e => correctMoney(e, {forDisplay: true, classOfDomElement: 'resOne,resTwo', showPoint: false}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="correctMoney">
```

P. S. `correctMoney` и `correctmoney` - разные вещи.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил в код только  e => и заработало, а где можно прочитать про эту строку? (я не имею ввиду обычные стрелочные ф-ции, то где вы прочитали что можно таким образом передавать событие в ф-цию)

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, не понял Вашей просьбы. Про стрелочные функции можно прочитать тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions В слушатели событий всегда передаётся аргументом объект события с полезной информации о событии.

Comment: я в первый раз вижу такую строку e => где либо кроме как стрелочных функций, по этому и спрашиваю, где вы прочитали что таким образом можно передать объект события в функуию?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, это и есть стрелочная функция. `e` - это объект события. Всё по канону :)